# How can I find the top three test scores + names from my array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have completed the first two steps of my assignment as to how my teacher wanted me to, which were to: 
calculate and print the average score for each exam
calculate and print the average score for each student, and the top scoring student

and now I can't figure out how to get it so it displays the top THREE scoring student's and their scores

***I want to do this without sorting the array is ascending/descending order***

My code so far is:

```
public class GradeBook {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] names = {"Alex", "Barry","Cindy", "Deb", "Eric", "Fran", "Gary", "Helen"};

    int[][] grades = {
            { 77, 83, 96 },
            { 88, 67, 78 },
            { 92, 77, 76 },
            { 94, 42, 81 },
            { 99, 54, 72 },
            { 90, 46, 54 },
            { 76, 59, 88 },
            { 94, 69, 88 }
    };

    int rSize = grades[0].length;
    int cSize = grades.length;
    double avg = 0;
    double maxNum = 0;
    double avgSc = 0;
    ArrayList<Double> avgScores = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList topThree = new ArrayList();

    // calculate and print the average score for each exam
    for (int r = 0; r < rSize; r++) {
        avg = 0;

        for (int c = 0; c < cSize; c++) {
            avg += grades[c][r];
        }

        avg /= cSize;
        DecimalFormat a = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        double x = Double.parseDouble(a.format(avg));

        System.out.println("\nThe average grade for Exam #" + (r+1) + ": " +x);
    }


    // calculate and print the average score for each student, and the top scoring student
    for (int c = 0; c < cSize; c++) {
        avgSc = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < rSize; r++) {
            avgSc += grades[c][r];

        }

        avgSc /= rSize;
        DecimalFormat a = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        double x = Double.parseDouble(a.format(avgSc));

        System.out.println("\nThe average grade for " + names[c] + ": " +x);
        avgScores.add(avgSc);

    }

    maxNum = 0;
    int topI = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i<cSize; i++) {

        if (avgScores.get(i) > maxNum){
            maxNum = avgScores.get(i);
            topI = i;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    DecimalFormat a = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    double x = Double.parseDouble(a.format(maxNum));
    System.out.println("\nThe top scoring student is: " + names[topI] + ", who has an average score of: " + x);

    double top1 = 0;
    double top2 = 0;
    double top3 = 0;
    String name1 = "";
    String name2 = "";
    String name3 = "";

    // Some loop that gets the top 3 students and their scores


    }

}
```

Comment: Just try to find the first top scoring student, then, think about how can you find the second, then third. One loop can do the job.

Comment: I think assignment is about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm. There probably good duplicate for Java... (CR have almost copy-paste ready solution http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91764/find-the-kth-largest-element-of-an-array)

Comment: Here's a very basic approach. Loop through the array, and store the first content in a variable. While looping through the array, compare the content of the array to the variable if the value is greater. If it is greater, store it. If not, skip it. With this approach, you can find the top scoring student. Once you have that, you can repeat for second and third by skipping the result you have.

Comment: @PhamTrung I have the loop for the top scoring student already, I'm just a bit lost on how to go through the unordered list, get a number, then if something else is higher than that number, make the new number the "top" number, and the old top number the "second" top number, etc until the top three are chosen

Comment: @Aaron ah that makes sense, I don't know why I didn't think of skipping the number that has the highest value once I've gotten it

Comment: @Aaron how can I "skip" something (the top student and then eventually the top 2 students) in a loop?

Comment: @MichaelG Well, how you would you skip something? Think about it. To skip something in this particular situation, you would need to keep track of what you need to skip.

Comment: I figured it out, thank u ! @Aaron

Comment: @MichaelG To help you approach algorithms such as this, imagine you had a really small sample size. For example, two students. Develop the algorithm for the small sample size, then it should work on a bigger sample. Solving smaller problems are easier.

Comment: I like that way of thinking @Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possible ways I can think of:

1. Sorting. Ref: http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/off-topic-31/java-enter-number-of-students-enter-grades-and-nam-544969/
2. Selection Algorithm (find kth largest element). Ref: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=182717
3. Simply loop over the scores and corresponding student to find the top three students.